# DD to local QNAP

Tags: backup, iso-image, dd, qnap

**ORIGINAL Q:**

Trying to backup a full drive via DD to a QNAP, but it's not as simple as a DD from regular drive to regular drive.

How do I DD to a QNAP?  The QNAP is local.

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Enabled SSH but unable to login via terminal:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled `SSH` at the QNAP it is quiet simple:

```
dd if=/dev/sda | ssh -C <admin-account>@<QNAP-IP-Address> dd of=/path/to/store/disk.img
```

Comment: Please see update 1.

Comment: Set the ssh server's port number to `22` and make sure to use an administrator account to login via ssh.